# How to limit zoom level in OpenLayers 2.x

Tags: wms, openlayers-2, zoom

I would like to have only 3 levels of zoom available (from level 6 to level 8).

```
demolayer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"abc...","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms",
{layers: 'def...', transparent:"true", format: 'image/png', numZoomLevels: 3, minZoomLevel: 6 },{isBaseLayer:false},

{ tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256,256)});

map.addLayer(demolayer2);

 map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')}));

map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(-4.601615515076983,39.8769407866263,-3.0527184873294764,41.16710732525929));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing that (don't know if it's the only way) is by passing an array of available resolutions to the map constructor via the options parameter. Something like...

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    resolutions: [0.02197265625, 0.0439453125, 0.17578125]
});
```

A way to get the resolutions you are interested in could be:

1) zoom your map to a desired zoom level (I did it via console by running `map.zoomTo(x)` where `x` is the zoom level I was interested in)

2) via the console log the `map.resolution` and take note of it

3) repeat for all the zoom levels you would like to include

You can find more in-depth information [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels).

Answer (score 7):

In *OlpenLayers 3* you can just initialize your [view](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html) with the desired zoom constraints:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    // ...
    view: new ol.View({
        maxZoom: 8,
        minZoom: 6,
        zoom: 7
    })
});
```

Comment: I changed the question title to make it specific to OpenLayers 2.x, as the API is very different from version 3. You might consider creating a new question for version 3.

Comment: @mettjus "I changed the question title to make it specific to OpenLayers 2.x" - I do not think that is a valid edit.

Comment: I asked for moderator intervention. We'll see what they suggest, if they do. Absolutely not meaning to invalidate your answer just trying to make the question more helpful for new comers.

Comment: @mettjus I understand. I'm not sure either which is the best solution. I made a meta discussion, feel free to add your 2 cents: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268244/making-a-question-product-version-specific-in-an-edit/268257

Answer (score 6):

just add the following code to your script:

```
map.isValidZoomLevel = function(zoomLevel) {
        return ((zoomLevel != null) && (zoomLevel >= 6) && (zoomlevel <= 8));
}
```

Comment: I just love when you google and google and try things out, and after 20 minutes you find the right answer like this and it's sweet. Made my morning.

Answer (score 0):

This should also be possible by setting numZoomLevels and maxResolution (maybe easier than individually finding all resolutions):

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    numZoomLevels: 15, 
    maxResolution: 39135.758475
});
```

Note: resolution for a given zoom level is previous zoom level's resolution divided by 2.